# How can i filter specific data to display in angular data table

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

I have to work on a project using angular 7 frameworks. I have a lot of data to be read and display. however, from the given raw data, I have to remove the trial units based on 'userName' data.

i have different username that for the 'userName' data. as for example given: **user22abc@ngul, user23abc@ngul, user67abc@ngul** etc... those are the sample 'userName' that need to be remove as is indicate the trial actually. therefore, i need to know what is the specific syntax i can apply in my writing. thanks!

I have 50 trial units from my raw data and I need to remove them all. Can anyone suggests and guide me what and where to use as the current code did not work solve the issue? I already browse the samples and solutions, but I am not able to understand it well. herewith I attached the sample coding.

Thanks.

Comment: you can create a pipe to filter the data, also post the code that  have  you tried so far

Comment: hi, i have attached the sample in picture above. thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the exact structure of your data that you want to display on your datatable, but I shall assume the most common use case, which is an array of objects in a format similar to this:

```
const original = [
  {
    userName: 'user22abc@ngu',
    name: 'aaa',
    id: 'aaa1'
  },
  {
    userName: 'user33azzz@ngu',
    name: 'bbb',
    id: 'bbb1'
  },
]
```

I will be using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a shallow copy of the original array. This is to ensure that any mutation will not affect the original array. This is followed by applying the `Array.filter()` method to filter out the array of objects with the matching username.

```
const filteredCopy = [...original].filter(row => row['username'] !== 'user22abc');
console.log(filteredCopy);
```

---

EDIT: If we need to filter it from an array of usernames, we have to make some modifications. The custom function that I have passed to filter() actually checks for 2 conditions:

1) I have made use of [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which actually checks if the array of usernames contains the username for that particular element. By negating that statement (using `!`), I have essentially returned the elements whose username is not part of the `usernameList` array.

2) I checked if the leading 4 characters of the username matches the string `user`.

```
const original = [
  {
    username: 'user22abc@ngu',
    name: 'aaa',
    id: 'aaa1'
  },
  {
    username: 'user33azzz@ngu',
    name: 'bbb',
    id: 'bbb1'
  },
  {
    username: 'user11@ngu',
    name: 'bbb',
    id: 'bbb1'
  },
  {
    username: 'bzzzz@ngu',
    name: 'bbab',
    id: 'bbb12'
  },
]

const usernameList = ['user22abc@ngu', 'user11@ngu'];

const filtering = usernameList => {
  const filteredCopy = [...original].filter(row => !usernameList.includes(row['username']) && row['username'].substring(0,4) === 'user');
  return filteredCopy;
}

filtering(usernameList);
```

Do take note that `.includes()` is part of ES7, thus it is not supported by some of the older browsers, such as Internet Explorer.

Comment: Minor suggested edit though. It should be row['username'] !== 'user22abc'

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya Oh right! Thanks for catching that mistake!

Comment: @wnf9543 ok, so you are passing `userName`, which is actually a variable?

Comment: Or wait, do you mean it comes in an array? Basically we have to filter out the array of usernames?

Comment: @wentjun yea, it comes in array `json` format. and yes! i want to filter that `userName`which indicates trial users.

Comment: @wnf9543 alright! I have updated my answer. I assume your json list has the usernames in the format I specified on my code?

Comment: @wentjun, thanks! i think your answer is almost there but my json list consist various details. to filter it, i declare which 'userName' should be deleted. that is my issue rn. as my `userName` mix with non trial user. i just want to filter the `userName`  that has something like **user22abc@ngul** (as the **user** word with digits indicate the trial user)

Comment: @wnf9543 ok.. So you only want the returned list to contain only non-trial users ?

Comment: @wnf9543 in that case, it is actually quite simple. I have made some changes to the above solution. I have taken into account of the filtering away of the trial users.

Comment: @wentjun thanks for the solution! currently working on it as it meet my requirements. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.newArray = new Array();
for(const entry of this.yourArray) {
 if(entry.userName !== 'user22abc@ngul')
  this.newArray.push(entry.userName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code i understand that you want to remove those objects from the array whose `userName` key is `user22abc@ngul`. For this you can use filters as shown below

```
this.newArray = this.oldArray.filter((item) => item.userName !== 'user22abc@ngul')
```

What the above code will do is , it will filter out all those objects whose userName is not `user22abc@ngul`. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. i have different username that for the 'userName' data. as for example given: **user22abc@ngul, user23abc@ngul, user67abc@ngul**. those are the sample 'userName' that need to be remove as is indicate the trial actually. therefore, i need to know what is the specific syntax i can apply in my writing. thanks!

Comment: Where do you have these usernames. are these in an any kind of array or you want to just hardcode these things

Comment: those usernames are read from raw data in `json` format. for some file, i already applied the same method as suggested and it works previously. but for this file, it has different characters and as i mentioned I have **50 trials username** that need to be remove.